# Forms with multiple element types using custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, forms

I am building a forms component and am looking for the following functionality. Each form would have multiple questions and multiple question types ( like text boxes, radio buttons, selection drop downs). How do we implement this with custom post types?

This is what I did - Created a custom post type with custom fields. How do I edit custom fields? Ideally, I would like a drop-down with various question types and after selecting the question type, a new instance of that element is created to which data can be added. Can all of this be done with meta data or am I looking at it the wrong way??

Answer (score 0):

WordPress meta data is primarily defined as storage mechanism. That is it doesn't dictate or offer interface options for interacting with it (sans rather meek native meta box).

Your options for interface are either developing it from scratch from your needs or making use of one of multiple frameworks available around.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Could you shed some more light on the option of developing from scratch? The custom-post-type currently supports some elements like editor, author, custom fields etc., Can I create a completely new element, say, for forms inside the custom-post-type?